# PostgreSQL 10 Rowtype Bug in Function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, postgresql-10

I declare inside a function the following:

```
SEL_USER  APP.USER % ROWTYPE;
```

Then i made the select

Working perfectly:

```
SELECT *
INTO   SEL_USER
FROM   APP.USER
WHERE  ...
```

But this isn't working and i don't know the reason.
Maybe a postgresql bug?

```
SELECT USER_ID, OFFICE_FK, LOCKER, EMAIL, FULL_NAME, SURNAME1 
       SURNAME2, SOCIAL_CARD, BIRTHDATE, PREFERENCES
INTO   SEL_USER
FROM   APP.USER
WHERE  ...
```

To clarify:

- Where statement are the same and it works.
- There is no error of fields because if I do the select without the into it works.

what happened?

- It's changing the fields, example:

  - locker_id is assigned the value of social_card (I verify that the values ​​are where they should go)
  - some fields are null (which is not possible because they are declared as not null)

Is it a postgresql 10 bug or am I doing something wrong?

In case I'm doing something bad I would appreciate it if you would help me.

(forgive  my english)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk create you both table and do query here for full scenario

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=69050f7fb00049e0a59665f9b9925ef6 working fine

Comment: When one record assigned to another one values assigning not by names but by order. It seems that you shuffle fields order in the second query against the original order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sincerely I do not know why it only gave me problems in that function, 
maybe it was some context problem, because in others it did not matter the order or if any column was missing.

Fix it by putting in order and using 'as'

```
SELECT  U.USER_ID, U.OFFICE_FK, U.LOCKER, U.SOCIAL_CARD, U.EMAIL, 
        U.FULL_NAME, U.SURNAME1, U.SURNAME2, U.BIRTHDATE, U.PREFERENCES
INTO    SEL_USER 
FROM    APP.USER AS U
WHERE   ...;
```

Thanks for your time :)